# Certain algebraic dependence of two polynomials

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $u,v,d \in \mathbb{C}[t]$ be three polynomials such that $\deg(u) \geq 1,\deg(v) \geq 1,\deg(d) \geq 2$.

Assume that $\gcd(u,v)=\gcd(u,d)=\gcd(v,d)=1$, and denote $U=du$ and $V=dv$.

Further assume that there exists $H(x,y) \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ with $H(0,0)=0$ (= without constant term) satisfying $H(U,V)=0$.

> Is it true that necessarily $H=0$?

**A special case:** If $\deg(H)=1$, then $H=\lambda x+\mu y$, hence $0=H(U,V)=\lambda du+ \mu dv= d(\lambda u + \mu v)$, so $\lambda u + \mu v =0$ which is impossible, unless $\lambda=\mu=0$ (otherwise, $\lambda u= - \mu v$ which implies that $\gcd(u,v)=u$, contradicting $\gcd(u,v)=1$).

However, if $\deg(H) \geq 2$, things may be more complicated.

There is a nice result which says the following: 
Given nonconstant $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[t]$: $f,g$ are algebraically dependent over $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[h]$, for some $h \in \mathbb{C}[t]$; see [this](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa92/aa9213.pdf) or [Corollary 1.3](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/39334102.pdf) (for one direction).

By the nice result we know that $U,V \in \mathbb{C}[h]$, for some $h \in \mathbb{C}[t]$.
Please notice that I assume a specific algebraic dependence, namely, one which satisfies $H(0,0)=0$; hopefully, this fact is relevant.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d=t^2$, $u=t+1$, and $v=t-1$.  Then $U+V=2t^3$ and $U-V=2t^2$, so $U$ and $V$ satisfy $H(U,V)=0$ where $H(x,y)=2(x+y)^2-(x-y)^3$.

In fact, such a nonzero $H$ always exists.  Indeed, since $U$ and $V$ are algebraically dependent there exists $H\neq 0$ such that $H(U,V)=0$.  Now just observe that the constant term of such an $H$ must be $0$, since otherwise $H(U,V)$ would be nonzero mod $d$.

Comment: Very nice! Please, what if $d$ is separable? (do not have multiple roots); this is actually the case I am interested in. Moreover, if there is a nonzero such $H$ for separable $d$, is there a 'plausible' (= not too strong) condition that guarantees that such $H=0$? (for example: $u,v,d$ are all separable?).

Comment: Yes, I understand, if $H(x,y)=\sum \sum h_{ij}x^iy^j$, then if $\alpha$ is a root of $d$, then $0=H(U,V)(\alpha) =h_{00}$.

Comment: Perhaps what I really wanted to ask is:  How can we guarantee that there exist no $h \in \mathbb{C}[t]$ with $U,V \in \mathbb{C}[h]$?

Comment: Actually, $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[t]$ must always be algebraically dependent, since we can take $h=t$..